# How to get a file reference URL in Swift?

Tags: swift, cocoa, filesystems, nsurl

I cannot get a file reference URL to work in Swift. First, Swift's `URL` type doesn't even define a method to convert a file path URL to a file reference URL. `NSURL` has such a method: `fileReferenceURL() -> URL?`, but I cannot figure out how to get it to work.

What I tried:

```
let myURL = URL(string: "file:///Users/Me/Desktop/CoolFolder")!
let refURL = (myURL as NSURL).fileReferenceURL()!
NSLog("\(myURL)")   // file:///Users/Me/Desktop/CoolFolder (ok)
NSLog("\(refURL)")  // file:///Users/Me/Desktop/CoolFolder (wha?!?)
logFolderContents() // Logs contents of folder pointed to by refURL
// ...
// Rename CoolFolder -> UncoolFolder in Finder.
// ...
logFolderContents() // Fails!
// ...
// Rename UncoolFolder -> CoolFolder.
// ...
logFolderContents() // Successfully logs contents again.
```

Basically, `refURL` continues to point at the original file path. The call to `fileReferenceURL()` seemingly did nothing.

How can I get a file reference URL in Swift?

**Update:**
User @Sam points out in the comments that this appears to be a Swift 3 regression bug as documented here: https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-2728. Please visit the link and vote on this bug. The thread also contains a workaround.

Comment: What value did you expect `refURL` to have?

Comment: I expected it to look something like this: file:///.file/id=6571367.2773272/. File reference URLs don't contain path names, but rather a unique ID. When the path names change (resource was renamed or moved), the ID still points to the same resource. See https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/AccessingFilesandDirectories/AccessingFilesandDirectories.html

Comment: As a test, change your 1st line to: `let myURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/Users/Me/Desktop/CoolFolder")`

Comment: @rmaddy Same result.

Comment: Looks like this is a known bug: https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-2728

Comment: @Sam Thank you. I didn't even know about this site.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, the bug still is not fixed as of April 2021. This makes comparing file URLs for equality quite difficult.

With ObjC this works well:

```
NSString *p1 = @"/etc/hosts";
NSString *p2 = @"/private/etc/hosts";
    
NSURL *url1 = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:p1];
NSURL *url2 = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:p2];
    
NSURL *ref1 = url1.fileReferenceURL;
NSURL *ref2 = url2.fileReferenceURL;
    
BOOL equal = [ref1 isEqual:ref2];
```

In Swift, I got practically the same result (i.e. a 64 bit in containing both the volume ID and the file ID) with this code:

```
let p1 = "/etc/hosts"
let p2 = "/private/etc/hosts"

let url1 = URL(fileURLWithPath: p1)
let url2 = URL(fileURLWithPath: p2)

// This does not work because the refs do not use fileIDs as they should
// See https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-2728
let ref1bad = (url1 as NSURL).fileReferenceURL()!
let ref2bad = (url2 as NSURL).fileReferenceURL()!
let equalBad = ref1bad == ref2bad
print("\(ref1bad) = \(ref2bad): \(equalBad)")

// This works:
var ref1: NSObject?
var ref2: NSObject?
if let resourceValues = try? url1.resourceValues(forKeys: [.fileResourceIdentifierKey]) {
    ref1 = resourceValues.fileResourceIdentifier as? NSObject
}
if let resourceValues = try? url2.resourceValues(forKeys: [.fileResourceIdentifierKey]) {
    ref2 = resourceValues.fileResourceIdentifier as? NSObject
}
let equal = ref1!.isEqual(ref2) // the use of "!" is probably not good here
print("\(String(describing: ref1)) = \(String(describing: ref2)): \(equal)")
```

If you wanted a real file reference URL, you'd have to reconstruct the URL from the two 32 bit values in the object (which appears to be of type `NSData`) and use the first as the fileID and the second as the volumeID. Writing the code for that exceeds my currently rather meager Swift skills, though.

Comment: Thanks for following up on this old question. I basically gave up on Swift a while ago, in part due to this issue. May revisit some day once it has matured. Yay for Obj-C.